# hacer que una accion de un controlador guarde en dos tablas en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Soy nuevo en rails, tengo que guardar datos en dos tablas simultaneamiento, la consulta seria es posible, y como seria esa implementación?

Answer (score 0):

si es posible.
dentro de la acción del controlador puedes usar el new o el create de las 2 tablas, por ejemplo:

```
tabla1.new(atributos)
tabla1.save
tabla2.new(atributos)
tabla2.save
```

saludos!